# spring batch admin email notification plugin

Tags: spring, email, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using spring batch admin as a web interface for administering the batch jobs. I would like to have some way to notify a set of email addresses that batch job is completed. Is there any plugin to spring batch admin that will allow me to accomplish what I want?

P.S. I have tried googling spring batch admin email notification plugin, but I could not find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch Admin does not provide this functionality.  However, it is easily added to your job via a JobExecutionListener.  You can implement your own to send the emails or you may be able to do it with Spring Integration (without writing code) but I'd have to play with it a bit to be sure.

Comment: Can you explain more with Spring Integration?

Comment: Using Spring Integration, you can specify a gateway to essentially imitate a Spring Batch listener.  Two places to look at how to do this is Gunnar Hillart's example on using Spring Batch and Spring Integration (look at how the notificationExecutionsListener is configured): https://github.com/ghillert/spring-batch-integration-sample/tree/master/payment-import-async-processor and this example on sending emails using Spring Integration: http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2010/08/09/sending-outbound-smtp-messages-through-gmail-with-spring-integration/